# Sub Sub Menu Code Broken?

Tags: html, css, submenu

Not sure where I am going wrong. Can't seem to get my Sub Sub Menu to display under the "Supai" tab. Where am I going wrong? I can get the Sub Menu to work, but somehow the Sub Sub will not display. Ugh

Also, I am sure you are tired of these Sub Sub Menu questions. I've dug through them and have even used the exact code used in responses on this website. They work fine.....until I paste them into my blog on blogger. Thinking there may be something working against me within the Blogger code itself. Thoughts?

```css
#cssnav {
     float: left;
    font: bold 12px Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
     border: 2px solid #74BA94;
     border-top: 1px solid #747BBA;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     overflow: hidden;
}

#cssnav ul {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
}

#cssnav ul li {
 float:left;
}

#cssnav ul li a {
    float: left;
 color:#EA1047;
     padding: 10px 20px;
 text-decoration:none;
     background:#3F10EA;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(59,63,65)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(72,76,77)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(75,77,77)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
 border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#cssnav ul li a:hover,
#cssnav ul li:hover > a {
     color: #252525;
     background:#3C4042;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77,79,79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67,70,71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69,70,71)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
     text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 -1px #000;

}

#cssnav li ul a:hover, 
#cssnav ul li li:hover > a  {
    color: #2c2c2c;
   background: #5C9ACD;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.17, rgb(61,111,177)), color-stop(0.51, rgb(80,136,199)), color-stop(1, rgb(92,154,205)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61,111,177) 17%, rgb(80,136,199) 51%, rgb(92,154,205) 100% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61,111,177) 17%, rgb(80,136,199) 51%, rgb(92,154,205) 100% );
     border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
     border-top: 1px solid #7BAED9;
     text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

#cssnav li ul {
     background:#3C4042;
     background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77,79,79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67,70,71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69,70,71)) );
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
     background-image: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
     border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
     left: -999em;
     margin: 35px 0 0;
     position: absolute;
     width: 160px;
     z-index: 9999;
     box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset; 
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset; 
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset; 
     border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#cssnav li:hover ul {
     left: auto;
}

#cssnav li ul a {
     background: none;
     border: 0 none;
     margin-right: 0;
     width: 120px;
     box-shadow: none;
     -moz-box-shadow: none;
     -webkit-box-shadow: none;
     border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
     border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

#cssnav li li ul {
     margin: -1px 0 0 160px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
     border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
     visibility:hidden;
}

#cssnav li li:hover ul {
     visibility:visible;
}

#cssnav ul ul li:last-child > a {
 -moz-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
 border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
}

#cssnav li:hover ul ul {
  display:none; // hide the unordered list that is inside the unordered list
}
#cssnav li ul li:hover ul {
  display:block; // display the unordered list in the same way as your sub menu
}
#cssnav ul ul ul li:first-child > a {
 -moz-border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
 border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html> 
<div id="cssnav">
<ul>
 <li><a href="www.example.com">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/about-me.html">About Me</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/joc-series.html">JOC: Book Series</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/adventures.html">Adventures</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/adventures.html#SUP">Supai</a></li>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Supai Walkthrough</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">The Drive</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/adventures.html#HTP">Hilltop</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/adventures.html#TRK">VillageTrek</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/adventures.html#VLG">Village</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/adventures.html#NJF">Navajo Falls</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/adventures.html#HSF">Havasu Falls</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/adventures.html#CMP">Campground</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/adventures.html#MNF">Mooney Falls</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/adventures.html#BTK">Beaver Trek</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/adventures.html#BVF">Beaver Falls</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/adventures.html#CTK">Colorado River Trek</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/adventures.html#CRV">Colorado River</a></li>
    </ul>
   <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/adventures.html#NSW">Never Summer Wilderness</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/adventures.html#RRG">Red River Gorge</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/adventures.html#YEL">Yellowstone</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/adventures.html#SNP">Sequoia Nat'l Park</a></li>
  </ul>
 <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/contest.html">Contest</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://www.example.com/p/fire.html">Fire Basics</a>
</li></li></ul>
</div>

</!doctype>
```

Answer (score 1):

Every submenu `ul` has to be *inside*  of an `li` element of the higher level menu, so this code...

```
<li><a href="http://www.journeysofthecrew.com/p/adventures.html#SUP">Supai</a></li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Supai Walkthrough</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Drive</a></li>
          [ etc. ]
        <li><a href="http://www.journeysofthecrew.com/p/adventures.html#CRV">Colorado River</a></li>
     </ul>
```

...should be

```
<li><a href="http://www.journeysofthecrew.com/p/adventures.html#SUP">Supai</a>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Supai Walkthrough</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">The Drive</a></li>
       [ etc. ]
       <li><a href="http://www.journeysofthecrew.com/p/adventures.html#CRV">Colorado River</a></li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

(moved closing `li` tag)

Comment: OK, I will try that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

place your sub submenu (contained in another ul tag) within the list tag and style as follows:

```
#cssnav ul li:hover #cssnav ul li ul li{
  left:100%;
  overflow:visible;
  top: 0px;
margin: 0px;
left: 100%;
}
#cssnav ul li ul:hover {
  visibility:visible;
  overflow:visible;
}
```

[click here for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/xc9L21Ln/)

Comment: I do not understand. @repzero, your code works great here, but when I copy and paste it into blogger I can only get a Sub Menu and not a Sub Sub menu. I am at my wits end with this. http://www.journeysofthecrew.com/

Comment: Can you create a pen or fiddle with the entire contents of the page? It could be some rules is affecting the expected behaviour

Comment: go to this site https://jsfiddle.net/ create an account for free... enter your codes inside the html section...save the fiddle and put the link in your question

Comment: OK..., I'll try that.

Comment: Got code pasted in. Sub Sub Menu works fine there, just not on Blogger's website. Figures... https://jsfiddle.net/abhxy4e1/

Comment: Okay I forked your snippet....see the link in my question...note I added the css rules in the css section in the fiddle..you can copy the rules and place it in your style tag in your html webpage

Comment: Note: you don't have to put the rules in your html section for it to work in your FIDDLE. it will work as is. But in your actual webpage file you place the codes in your css style tag

Comment: I have no idea how you figured that out, but I sure do thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
    title: "Menu",
    breakpoint: 768,
    format: "multitoggle"
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background: #3b3f41;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ef547b;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #cccccc;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #ef547b;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ef547b;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 23px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 35px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  padding: 11px 15px;
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #99cdf5;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 11px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 17px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center > ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li,
#cssmenu.small-screen li:hover > ul > li {
  height: auto;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 35px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  color: #ef547b;
  background: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li.active > a {
  color: #cccccc;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-right ul ul {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 17px;
  color: #ef547b;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 17px;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ef547b;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ef547b;
  content: '';
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 17px;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #ef547b;
  content: '';
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
  top: 23px;
  border: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 15px;
  background: #cccccc;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
  top: 23px;
  background: #cccccc;
  width: 15px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
  background: #2f3234;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button {
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 19px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #ef547b;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button:after {
  top: 15px;
  right: 13px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
  background: #cccccc;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 22px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ef547b;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button:before {
  top: 12px;
  right: 16px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen.select-list {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- MenuMaker Plugin -->
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/menumaker/menumaker.min.js"></script>

<!-- Icon Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">JOC: Book Series</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> Adventures</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Supai</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Supai Walkthrough</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">The Drive</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Hilltop</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">VillageTrek</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Village</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Navajo Falls</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Havasu Falls</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Campground</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Mooney Falls</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Beaver Trek</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Beaver Falls</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Colorado River Trek</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Colorado River</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Never Summer Wilderness</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Red River Gorge</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Yellowstone</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sequoia Nat'l Park</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Contest</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Fire Basics</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```